# filter fullcalendar events with select(not work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I need to filter the events that are displayed on the screen using a select. I am using .change to send the value of the selected option and the screen is refreshed, but I have not been successful.The events are displayed correctly if I remove the WHERE.  I think the model is not getting the value of rut_usu. Any help is welcome.

Controller ( cCalendar )

```
public function geteventos(){

 $rut_usu = $this->input->post('rut_jc');

 $r = $this->mCalendar->geteventos();
 echo json_encode($r, $rut_usu); 

}
```

Model (mCalendar)

```
public function geteventos($rut_usu){


$this->db->select('CONCAT(estudiantes.pnombre," ", estudiantes.apellido_pa," ", estudiantes.apellido_ma,", ",motivos_citas.descripcion_mot) As title ,citas.id_ci id, citas.fecha_ini start, citas.fecha_ter end, citas.id_mot mot, CONCAT(estudiantes.pnombre," ", estudiantes.apellido_pa," ", estudiantes.apellido_ma) as estudiante');
$this->db->select('CONCAT(usuarios.pnombre," ", usuarios.apellido_pa," ", usuarios.apellido_ma) as jefe_c, estudiantes.rut_estu rut_estudiante');
$this->db->from('citas');
$this->db->join('estudiantes', 'citas.rut_estu = estudiantes.rut_estu');
$this->db->join('motivos_citas','citas.id_mot = motivos_citas.id_mot');
$this->db->join('usuarios','citas.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
$this->db->where('rut_usu',$rut_usu); 

return $this->db->get()->result();


}
```

Javascript (send select value to filter events)

```
  $("#rut_jc").change(function(){;

   //rut_jc is the name of the select

  var rut_usu = $("#rut_jc").val();

  $.ajax({

   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "cCalendar/geteventos/",
   type: 'post',
   data: { "rut_jc": rut_usu },

    success: function(response){ 


       $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

   }

 });
```

Javascript (show the events)

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

     header: {
     left: 'prev,next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'

     },

      defaultDate: new Date(),
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      businessHours: true, // display business hours

      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

      $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>cCalendar/geteventos',

      { "start": start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "end": end.format("YYYY-MM-DD") },

       function (data) {

        callback($.parseJSON(data));

         });
       },

       dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

       date_last_clicked = $(this);

        $('#modal_registrar').modal();


        },

     eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {


      $('#event_id').val(event.id);
      $('#id_mot2').val(event.mot);
      $('#nombre_estudiante').val(event.estudiante);
      $('#jc2').val(event.jefe_c);
      $('#rut_estudiante').val(event.rut_estudiante)

       $('#start_f').val(moment(event.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));

        $('#end_f').val(moment(event.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));


       $('#modal_editar').modal();


       },


       minTime: "08:30:00",
       maxTime: "23:00:00"

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` it runs *another* ajax call (the one defined in the calendar's `events` option), separate to the one you made explicitly from the "change" handler. You're throwing away the response from that call where you included rut_jc / rut_usu. You don't do anything with it. So it's no surprise it doesn't affect the calendar.

Instead of making a separate, meaningless ajax call, simply integrate this new functionality into your existing code:

**Calendar Code**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'

  },
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  businessHours: true, // display business hours
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>cCalendar/geteventos', {
        "start": start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        "end": end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        "rut_jc": $("#rut_jc").val() //add the extra value to the existing filter parameters. fullCalendar can then use it directly.
      },
      function(data) {
        callback($.parseJSON(data));
      }
    );
  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    date_last_clicked = $(this);
    $('#modal_registrar').modal();
  },
  eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#event_id').val(event.id);
    $('#id_mot2').val(event.mot);
    $('#nombre_estudiante').val(event.estudiante);
    $('#jc2').val(event.jefe_c);
    $('#rut_estudiante').val(event.rut_estudiante)
    $('#start_f').val(moment(event.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
    $('#end_f').val(moment(event.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
    $('#modal_editar').modal();
  },
  minTime: "08:30:00",
  maxTime: "23:00:00"
});
```

**Change handler for the `<select>`**

```
$("#rut_jc").change(function(){;
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});
```

Additionally, you weren't passing the $rut_usu value to your model (instead, you just sent it back in the response, which made no sense).

N.B. I have also taken the liberty of adding the start/end dates sent by fullCalendar into your controller and model. As I mentioned in my answer to your earlier question a few days ago, you now need to alter your database query with another WHERE clause to ensure it only returns events which start or end between these two dates (inclusive).

**Controller**

```
public function geteventos(){

 $start = $this->input->post('start');
 $end = $this->input->post('end');
 $rut_usu = $this->input->post('rut_jc');

 $r = $this->mCalendar->geteventos($start, $end, $rut_usu);
 echo json_encode($r); 
}
```

**Model**

```
public function geteventos($start, $end, $rut_usu){
//...etc
```

Comment: Thank you again, I know quite a bit about this library, and JSON so I make a lot of mistakes but I need to use it. I got involved in the title process and they asked me for a dating system, I asked them on the internet and they recommended this bookstore to me.